# Edit table with a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

How can I only show the channel in the table that I pick from the select box?

```
<select>
    <option style="display:none;">Channel</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="onlineButcher">Online Butcher</option>
    <option value="theMeatSite">The Meat Site</option>
    <option value="bbqOnline">BBQ Online</option>
    <option value="weSellMeat">We Sell Meat</option>
</select>
```

These are my options so in the table below say I only wanted it to show rows with the channel Online Butcher?

```
<table class="orders">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Niche ID</th>
            <th>Channel</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Dispatch</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>012345678</td>
        <td>Online Butcher</td>
        <td>Mr D Jones</td>
        <td>Dispatch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>012345677</td>
        <td>The Meat Site</td>
        <td>Mr C Jones</td>
        <td>Dispatch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>012345676</td>
        <td>BBQ Online</td>
        <td>Mr B Jones</td>
        <td>Dispatch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>012345675</td>
        <td>We Sell Meat</td>
        <td>Mr A Jones</td>
        <td>Dispatch</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it makes sense.

I used this to sort my table using the headers, maybe something similar but instead of order only show certain channel.

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a "do-this-for-me"-site, but rather a "I tried this, didn't work, why not?"-site. Please provide us some code with what you've tried already, and then we can check how we can help you to improve it.

Comment: If I had a clue, ive tried researching and can't find anything not really worked with tables much, ill add the code i used to sort my rows.

Comment: You can do this fairly simply with javascript.  You might also find a javascript library such as `jQuery` somewhat useful in traversing / manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/3/ Instead of search text you pass your dropdown value to filter

Comment: With only html, how can you do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the text of the selected option and then use `filter()` to find the rows which contain that text and show them. Try this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var value = $('option:selected', this).text(); 
    var $allRows = $('table tbody tr').show();
    var $selectedRows = $allRows.filter(function() {
        return $('td:eq(1)', this).text() == value;
    });

    if ($selectedRows.length) {
        $allRows.hide();
        $selectedRows.show();
    }
}).change();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dumt2k8c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can first make all rows invisible then `filter` the rows by the text in `<td>`s and only `show` the rows returned after `filter`.

```
 $('select').change(function(){

        var filterby = $( "option:selected" ).text(); 
        $('tr').hide();
        $("td").filter(function() {
           return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterby) != -1; }).parent().show();
        });   
 }):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add id's to your  elements inside the  element that match your values in your dropdown, add an id to your  element then bind an event to the on change of the select to manipulate the display of the  elements.